# Call collapse/toggle methods from manage bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces

So far I have the following method on my view scope managed bean

```
 public void onRowToggle(ToggleEvent event) {
        question = (QuestionInTest) event.getData();
 }
```

This is fired by this ajax component which is inside my datatable

```
 <p:ajax event="rowToggle" listener="#{testBean.onRowToggle}" update="toggleQuestions"/>
```

So my question is that is possible call the toggle method from inside my managed bean keeping the row index that I am working on?

This is because I assign some value when the row is expanded

Comment: If you have the data, can't you use 'indexOf' ? And maybe the event or the component contains the index, get it from the facesContext component?

Comment: @Kukeltje I want to call in the managed bean because I have to do some logic and then I need to colapse and expand the row, this is because when I expand the row I refresh the row I tried something like this with no result     `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("jQuery('.ui-row-toggler.ui-icon-circle-triangle-s.click());");`, obviously this not have and index I just write this in order to check if something happend on the page because when I tried to update from the jsf page is not working

Comment: IndexOf IN the bean

Answer (score 0):

You can use `f:setPropertyActionListener` tag

```
<p:ajax event="rowToggle" listener="#{testBean.onRowToggle}" update="toggleQuestions">
 <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{testBean.clickedRowIndex}" value="rowIndex"/>
</p:ajax>
```